# Azure Cosmos DB - how to retrieve json attributes from a document similar like retrieving column names from SQL table

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb

```
{  
  "Volcano Name": "Agua de Pau",  
  "Country": "Portugal",  
  "Region": "Azores",  
  "Location": {  
    "type": "Point",  
    "coordinates": [  
      -25.47,  
      37.77  
    ]  
  },  
  "Elevation": 947,  
  "Type": "Stratovolcano",  
  "Status": "Historical",  
  "Last Known Eruption": "Last known eruption from 1500-1699, inclusive",  
  "id": "d44c94b6-81f8-4b27-4970-f79b149529d3",  
  "_rid": "Sl8fALN4sw4BAAAAAAAAAA==",  
  "_ts": 1448049512,  
  "_self": "dbs/Sl8fAA==/colls/Sl8fALN4sw4=/docs/Sl8fALN4sw4BAAAAAAAAAA==/",  
  "_etag": "\"0000443f-0000-0000-0000-564f7b680000\"",  
  "_attachments": "attachments/"  
}
```

In MS SQL, we have like below to read column names from a table.

select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where table_name = 'table_name' .

I am expecting the same for document db. is it possible
from the above sample document which has the Type "Stratovolcano" to retrieve the json names "Volcano Name", "Country", "Region", "Location"... etc

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As I am new to cosmos DB, i am still searching for solution.I knew the direct select query to retrieve the values. But for this, I didn't get any clue. If there is any suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: @DineshV - the Cosmos DB SQL API documentation is fairly thorough, including all the basic query clauses, filtering, projections, etc. I would suggest starting there. Also, your comment suggest you've tried something already - you should consider editing your question to show specifically what you tried.

Comment: @DavidMakogon...It's an interesting question (at least I am seeing such kind for the 1st time)! OP is interested in finding document schema using a select query.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS - yeah I saw that they posted that in a (now-deleted) comment, after my comment.

Answer (score 2):

An Azure Cosmos SQL container is a schema-agnostic container of items. The items in a container can have arbitrary schemas unlike rows in a table. So, Cosmos DB will not be able to do what you are asking for.

In your case it looks like all your items will have the same schema. So, you could do a " select * from c where c.id = "someid" " and infer the schema from the retuned item.